# If $x^T\!Ay=0$ for all $x,y $ in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ then $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Is it true that if $x^T\!Ay=0$ for all $x,y $ in $ \mathbb{R}^n$ then $A=0$.  If so how do I justify this statement?

Comment: Make sure I have correctly written your post in mathjax.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Take $x$ and $y$ to be standard unit vectors. What happens?

Comment: Well if I take (e_i)^TAej=0 then that implies that A_(ij)=0.  Then A=0.   Is this all it takes?

Comment: @1234 Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $Ay \neq 0$. Let $x=Ay$, then $x^TAy = \|Ay\|^2 >0$.

Hence $Ay=0$ for all $y$, or equivalently, $A=0$.

Comment: Is my comment above using standard basis vectors incorrect?

Comment: Your comment is correct, this is another way of looking at it.